# Force my application to use the market app, when i open my url

Tags: android, google-play

i have a button which must lunch download of an application. When i click the button android asked me how to open the link with browser or with market.
Can i force it to use the market app so it doesn't prompt?

Here is my code:

```
String url = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.scid.android";

Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

i.setData(Uri.parse(url));

startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `market://` URL syntax from [the Android developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html#marketintent):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=org.scid.android"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: i tired this, so i got other application, android suggest Agenda application,Barcode Scanner application, Facebook application, , twitter application and so many other

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, very accurately. You could try and get the Activity names of the Android Market app, but it's not a sure-shot way to do this stuff.

These are implicit intents, and since the data type is a URL, it's obvious that you will be presented with an options dialog.